# An algorithm to check if two DFA are disjoint

Tags: automata, finite-automata

What is the algorithm to check if two DFA are disjoint? I want to know if there exist any string accepted by both automata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct the [intersection DFA](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intersection-process-of-two-dfas/) of both DFA's. Then, check if there is a path from the starting state to any end state.

If there is a path, then the two DFA's are not disjoint. If there isn't, then they are.

Comment: Intersection can be defined in terms of complementation and union http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/gordon.pace/Research/Software/Relic/Transformations/FSA/intersection.html Maybe it will be useful for somebody like me.

Comment: Is there an algorithm to construct a few DFA that are disjoint for a given DFA?

Comment: What do you mean by that? If I understand correctly, construction the complement DFA will work

Comment: yes, construction the complement DFA will work. I am interested to generate few more. For example: given 1+ the desired set of DFA = {2+, 10+, 01+,...}. All of them are disjoint with 1+

Comment: Enumerate over all DFA's and for each one of them intersect it with the complement DFA.